# can selected/active items be clickable?

Tags: accessibility, human-interface-guideline

I am considering to design an icon based menu and to use the classic pattern: inactive, hover-state and selected.

However, I would like the user to be able to click on a menu element even if the state is active/selected, in order to toggle the displayed contents.

Is it a good practice to allow the user to click on an active/selected element?

Comment: So, 'click to select' and then when selected it's 'click to toggle'?

Comment: yes, that would be the pattern.

Comment: For what platform? Touch, Desktop, Web?

Comment: it's for a web application

Comment: Honestly, I do not see the use case here. Could you please include what the "displayed contents" in the menu is, how come a selection in a menu does not expand, and what the menu looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's a fine practice. The pattern is a "toggle button." A common example used by millions of people is formatting text. Check out this example from Gmail:

[image: gmail compose toggle button]